# Flask-React app, browser geting info from routes that dont exist

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I have a very simple Flask-React App with log in authentication.

The application works but when poking around a weird thing popped out and I cant for the life of me figure out what’s going on.

A bit of context.

I have a Flask backend running on port 5000 of my local machine.

This backend contains the routes to:

Log in:

```py
@api.route('/token', methods=["POST"])
def create_token():
    #todo: checar si quitar el none hace algo
    email = request.json.get("email", None)
    password = request.json.get("password", None)
    if email != "test" or password != "test":
        return {"msg": "Wrong email or password"}, 401

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=email)
    response = {"access_token":access_token}
    return response
```

Log out:

```py
@api.route("/logout", methods=["POST"])
def logout():
    response = jsonify({"msg": "logout successful"})
    unset_jwt_cookies(response)
    return response
```

And get some info:

```py
@api.route('/profile')
@jwt_required()
def my_profile():
    response_body = {
        "name": "Santiago",
        "about" :"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
    }
    jsonify(response_body)
    return response_body
```

I have a React front end running on port 3000 of my local machine.
I installed axios on it and configured the package.json file to have this line.

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
```

The App.js file looks like this

```js
function App() {
  const { token, removeToken, setToken } = useToken();
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header/>
        {!token && token!=="" &&token!== undefined?
        <Login setToken={setToken} />
        :(
          <>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Profile rmtoken={removeToken} token={token} setToken={setToken}/>}></Route>
              <Route exact path="*" element={<NotFound/>} ></Route>
            </Routes>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

This depending on whether the user has a token can redirect to the Log in form or the profile page

Here is the Log in form:

```js
    function logMeIn(event) {
      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url:"/token",
        data:{
          email: loginForm.email,
          password: loginForm.password
         }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        props.setToken(response.data.access_token)
      }).catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response)
          console.log(error.response.status)
          console.log(error.response.headers)
          }
      })
return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
          <form className="login">
            <input onChange={handleChange}
                  type="email"
                  text={loginForm.email}
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  value={loginForm.email} />
            <input onChange={handleChange}
                  type="password"
                  text={loginForm.password}
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  value={loginForm.password} />

          <button onClick={logMeIn}>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
```

Very simple page that uses the back end to generate tokens and the front end to store them.

And this works this all works, my problem was when thinking of deploying this application I wanted to check to exactly what port I was talking to from the browser.

When I click the “log me in” button in the Login form, the request is made to the route: localhost:3000/token.
[image]

Which as far as I understand does not exist.

The "/token" route lives on the back end which is hosted on port 5000, so i was expecting all the request to go to url:"http://localhost:5000/token"

But they are going to url:"http://localhost:3000/token" and as you can see the back end is actually getting the request, so this is working.

I have tried to figure this out but I just can’t, I thought React would present the button that makes the request to port 5000, and clicking it would make the browser make that post request to that port so it would look like a request made to 127.0.0.1:5000/token

Then maybe I though the button is just triggering the react function and React is doing the request on the background and giving the info back, that’s why the browser did not ever see port 5000, but that does not explain the route looking like that.

And this is happening in every request I make to the back end, i used the token one as an example but they are all the same, they apear to be going to localhost:3000 and then the route that i specified on the back end.

so my quesiton is, what is going on?

PD:
i followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/nagatodev/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-a-flask-and-react-application-23i7) to create this app.

Comment: presumably `url:"/token"` should be `url:"http://localhost:5000/token"` ?

Comment: yes, that is what iwas expecting to see, the requests made to url:"http://localhost:5000/token"

i edited the post hopully its a bit more clear

Comment: `@jwt_required()`  why are you calling the decorator here? ( in get some info)

Comment: when the  create_token() funciton is called though the /token end point the back end generates and send a jwt token.


the @jwt_required() decorator makes it so that when calling the /profile end point you must include a valid Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
heather or youll get a "Missing Authorization heather" as a response

Comment: proxy works only in dev mode, it wont be working if you build your app

Comment: ohh i did not know that, when buidling i should remove the proxy line and instead make the requests with the full absolute path?